# Pandas: Make a column with (1,2,3) if string of another column-Row value starts with ("A","B","C")

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe

I have dataframe with filenames and classification, these are predictions from a network, I want to map them into integers to evaluate prediction from a network.

My dataframe is :

```
Filename:             Class:


GHT347                  Europe
GHT568                  lONDON
GHT78                   Europe
HJU                      US
HJI                      lONDON
HJK                      US
KLO                      Europe
KLU                      lONDON
KLP                      lONDON
KLY1                    lONDON
KL34                    US
```

The true prediction should be :

GHT-- EUROPE
HJU -- US
KL -- London

I want to map : GHT and Europe to 1, US and HJ to 0, KL and London to 2 by adding an additional two columns Prediction and Actual

```
Actual Prediction
1           1
1           2
```

pandas str.startswith method returns true or false, here I want three values. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

i cannot fully understand what you want, but I can give you some tips

use regular expressions:

```
df['actual'] = np.nan
df.loc[(df.Filename.str.contains('^GHT.*')) & (df.Class == 'Europe'), 'Actual'] = 1
df.loc[(df.Filename.str.contains('^HJ.*')) & (df.Class == 'US'), 'Actual'] = 0
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can set column values to anything you like, based on the values of one or more other columns.  This toy example shows one way to do it:

```
row1list = ['GHT347', 'Europe']
row2list = ['GHT568', 'lONDON']
row3list = ['KLU', 'lONDON']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list],
                  columns=['Filename', 'Class'])

df['Actual'] = -1       # start with a value you will ignore
df['Prediction'] = -1

df.loc[(df['Filename'].str.startswith('GHT')) & (df['Class'] == 'Europe'), 'Actual'] = 1
df.loc[(df['Filename'].str.startswith('KL')) & (df['Class'] == 'lONDON'), 'Prediction'] = 2

print(df)
#   Filename   Class  Actual  Prediction
# 0   GHT347  Europe       1          -1
# 1   GHT568  lONDON      -1          -1
# 2      KLU  lONDON      -1           2
```